The similar-question panel is sometimes missing on Stack Exchange
The similar-question panel is sometimes missing on Stack Exchange. This makes it much harder for me to find old posts of mine or others' related posts. Is there any way to solve this?


This sounds like a question for [Meta.SE] since it's not about ELL specifically. Are you OK if I migrate it there, or would you like to check and see if others there have already asked this question first?

I actually posted it there first, and then a member told me that I should post it here.

Is it possible there are no questions similar to the word "inhabit"? What happens when you try something more common, like "gerund or infinitive"?

"Gerund or infinitive" did trigger the panel, but many others I tried which 100% in the titles of my old posts didn't.

Why are you using the form for posting a question as a search tool instead of just using the search tool? https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/searching

@KenAdams Were any of your proposed titles shorter than the minimum of 15 characters? I noticed sometimes the "Similar questions" list didn't pop up for titles shorter than that. And again, does this only happen on ELL, or does it happen on other sites you're a member of?

@ColleenVI have found that when I write a question the related questions it generates are quite on point. It's better at finding related questions than using the search box. Don't get me on about searching something via a tag, it's a painful and tiresome procedure.

If the OP wants to find their old posts they must look at their profile page. Where is it? https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/181523/ken-adams scroll down until you find newest questions

@Mari-LouA "Similar Questions" works better on completely typed out questions because it has more information to go on. If someone is just going to type one word in a box, they should just use the search. And the reason tags don't work for searching is because the community doesn't curate them and they are therefore mostly noise. A complete question plus tags can narrow things down a lot. Yes, the SE search UI sucks. I'm not arguing that it doesn't.

@ColleenV  I hadn't seen that the OP used a single-word for a title. I was just talking about my own experience, writing the full text complete with a proper title, the suggested "similar questions" actually does a good job. As for tags, I agree they don't work because they rarely reflect the notion of the language problem.

@Mari-LouA Tags aren't supposed to describe a single question; they're supposed to group questions of a similar theme together. The current implementation is really bad because it requires the person with the least amount of knowledge to decide which questions are similar to their own. It's completely backward. AI would probably pretty good at tagging (assuming it infers the tags and isn't trained with the current hot mess of tags).

@gotube yeah I realized that if I type some keywords and they are too short, the panel doesn't pop up. But if I type more, even if the added words are unrelated, the panel still pops up. I wonder why it has to be complicated like this.

@KenAdams Do you consider the issue closed, and the answer is to write a title of at least 15 characters? If so, I'll write an answer. If not, for the third time, does this only happen on ELL or on other SE sites as well?

Oh, sorry for forgetting to reply to that. I only use ELL so I'm not sure. And yeah, I think we've solved the problem.
